# High CPU usage when sending data using SOAP

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, gsoap, svc

We wrote in C# some webservice that sends and receives data from remote clients. It works fine. Few days ago we found that when sending back to client array of bytes CPU usage increases from about 2% to almost 30% on IIS worker process. During debugging we found that this CPU usage peak occurs after our webmethod ended, so probably this is nothing in our code. Is there something that we don't know that could cause such CPU usage? When we sends only an error code there is no such peak...

This CPU usage occurs when there is only one client connected. When we had 4-5 clients connected CPU was used in 100%!

Comment: This question could be salvaged with a little more information...

Answer (score 0):

With so little to go on, I'm assuming you will only get (educated) guesses.

Here's mine: Check if the GC was active (You can do this in PerfMon). If it was, are you allocating/deallocating lots of memory? Do you have long running transactions?

Maybe of Interest:

- [Optimizing WCF Web Service Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee377061.aspx)
- [.NET Debugging Demos Lab 4: High CPU hang](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2008/02/22/net-debugging-demos-lab-4-high-cpu-hang.aspx)